# I need to do something like form.save(commit=False) in my model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model that needs to include the ID in another field when its created... see below:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ticket_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

...

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    shortname = self.brand.shortname
    super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.ticket_number = shortname.upper() + '-' + str(self.id)
    super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works, which is good, and creates a unique ticket number. I'm new to Django, but I know enough that I feel like saving a post twice is inefficient. Is there something like .save(commit=False) for Models? I'd like to only save it once per save.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. What would it do, if it existed? And the database is responsible for setting the id anyway so how would this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really know in advance what `self.id` will be until the corresponding database row is created and Django extracts it from there. If you aren't planning on filtering on the column, you can just turn it into a property that's computed when you look it up on a model instance:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def ticket_number(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.brand.shortname.upper(), self.id)
```

Comment: That worked well, but I may not be able to use it. We need a way for people to be able to search by job number. I'm guessing that's easy enough to implement on the front-end though so I'll check and see.

Comment: @brunam: It's probably simpler to perform two saves than to rework your code to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_save` signal, to update the ticket number. The post_save signal gets called after your model is saved, hence it will have an id. Although, you will still be performing two saves, but you will only call save explicitly once.

Post save documentation: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save)
That will hopefully give you more mental peace =).